# The running time per epoch keeps increasing when using code torch.autograd.grad()

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, autograd

I am using torch.autograd.grad() function to calculate the grads for two loss functions (which is used to balance the weight of these two loss),

```
loss1_grads = torch.autograd.grad(loss1, model.parameters(), retain_graph=True) 
loss2_grads = torch.autograd.grad(loss2, model.parameters(), retain_graph=True)
.....
loss = loss1+alpha*loss2#alpha related to loss1_grads and loss2_grads
loss.backward()
```

when I added `torch.autograd.grad()` in my code, the running time of each epoch keeps increasing for each epoch, i.e., (epoch 50 : 0.5s, epoch 51 : 0.51s ,...., epoch 500 : 1s).

I don't know what happens, do I missed something?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have modified my answer.

Answer (score -1):

So there are two different flags in `torch.autograd` which helps in remembering the gradients of the variables in your code.

1. When we use `requires_grad=True`, PyTorch remembers the gradients till you call the `backward()` function and updates the variables and flushes out the gradients after calculations are over.
2. If you use `retain_graph=True`, Pytorch does not remove the gradients that have been used to compute backward, and then it gets subsequently sent to the next epochs of training. This adds a huge overload on your system as in the nth epoch you are going through your graph n-times when you call `.backward()` (not once which is what generally happens).

So in your code just adding `requires_grad=True` to all the variables is enough (like `your_tensor.requires_grad_(True)`) and the `retain_graph` flag is not required after the backward computation which can be freed up like `loss.backward(retain_graph=False)`.

Comment: I need the grads w.r.t loss1 and loss2 to balance these two loss, so I use ```retain_graph=True```, after that, I use loss.backward() for each epoch. So, where should I add this ```requires_grad=True``` in? it seems torch.autograd.grad don't have this parameter

Comment: I specifically said to add `requires_grad=True` to the tensors you have created in pytorch. You can also assign it as `your_torch_tensor.requires_grad_(True)`. And you can let go of the retained graph while doing backward as  `loss.backward(retain_graph=False)`. This does the backward grad computation and then frees up your graph. Editing my answer with this update.